# Latex editor with good intellisense?

Tags: latex, editor, intellisense

I have tried texmaker, and it has built-in "intellisense" autocompletion, but it fails to find most of the packages because it seems it only recognizes the most basic latex commands.

Do you know any intellisense editor with a good base of commands, or better yet an editor that dynamically extracts syntax from yourinstalled packages?

thanx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at KILE or TEXMAKER.

Comment: I tried texmaker... you know how to make it recognize more commands?

Comment: Not for texmaker, but Kile offers the posibility to add completenion files and some abbreviations and dictionaries through it's settings.

Answer (score 2):

The new Inlage Version just got an awesome autocompletion feature.

Features:

- Automatic resolving for all available LaTeX packages from the MikTeX list
- Autocompletion with descriptions for ~600 LaTeX commands
- Autocompletion with descriptions for 30 environments
- Autocompletion with descriptions for commented user commands
- Reference list for labels
- nice Icons for all symbols

More information here:

http://www.inlage.com/news/?p=159

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try TeXworks, as you can easily add more terms to the autocomplete list.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys i think i got the answer.
TexnicCenter has a "import tex commands" which searches for syntax from installed packages and then adds them to auto completion. Sweet. I prefer more minimalistic editors such as texmaker, but i think i can live with texnic.